# How to concat multiple fields with line breaks

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that has 5 columns I want to combine into one but with line breaks, i.e.

```
Select
concat(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) as MyQuery
from MyTable
```

I need to change this either in SQL table itself or as an insert function, so that there are line breaks, the field is formatted as medium text, so would look like this:

```
Line 1 
Line 2 
Line 3 
Line 4 
Line 5
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: `SELECT col1 UNION ALL col2 UNION all col3...`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be:

```
Select concat_ws('
', field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) as MyQuery
from MyTable;
```